# Why is "map with reverse lookup" not supported as a data structure?

Tags: data-structures

I asked this question on StackOverflow recently:

[Is there a Map in Java that supports looking up Keys by (non-Unique) Value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59933827/is-there-a-map-in-java-that-supports-looking-up-keys-by-non-unique-value/59934288#59934288)

As I suspected, the answer was "no", but I'm wondering why there is no data structure that captures the relationship in question:

`Value put(Key, Value)`

`List<Key> lookup(Value)`

Is a fairly common set of requirements, and it's one that is supported pretty commonly in database languages like SQL (e.g. `SELECT key WHERE value = ${val}`)

**So why do no major languages support this relationship**?

Note that this is different to a bi-map relationship, where the 1-1 relationship is enforced in both directions.

Comment: I think asking why is a very difficult question to answer ... try to ask a question that has a correct answer or solves a specific problem. Even if you knew why you are no closer to a solution

Comment: C++ has a library that implements of the functionality variations described in Lie Ryan's answer: [Boost MultiIndex](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/index.html). As Lie Ryan pointed out, the library's implementation is indeed very complicated, and is suitable for a language such as C++ where people want highest performance and no non-essential overhead at the cost of library's code complexity. Other languages eschew highly complicated implementations (even for their standard libraries), which means most programmers just use SQL for the same.

Comment: A simple answer to this complicated question is therefore, "because these languages typically have integrated access to SQL" (or at least SQLite), they don't need an implementation of bimap or generalized index within the standard library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So why do no major languages support this relationship?

It is supported as a *function*, e.g. in Java

```java
List<Key> keysWithValue(Map<Key, Value> map, Value value) {
    return map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getValue().equals(value))
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

or in C#

```cs
List<Key> keysWithValue<Key, Value>(this Dictionary<Key, Value> map, Value value) {
    return (from e in map
        where e.Value == value
        select e.Key).toList();
}
```

Which is strikingly similar to how your query would be written with linq-to-sql

```cs
IQueryable<Key> keysWithValue<Key, Value>(this IQueryable<KeyValuePair<Key, Value>> table, Value value) {
    return from e in table
        where e.Value == value
        select e.Key;
}
```

Aside: it does exist in C++, in the [boost bimap library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/boost_bimap/the_tutorial/controlling_collection_types.html).

```cpp
boost::bimap<boost::bimaps::set_of<Key>, boost::bimap::multiset_of<Value>> bimap;
auto keys = bimap.right.equal_range(value); // can loop over keys
```

(Or `unordered_set_of`, `unordered_multiset_of`)

Comment: `List<Key> keysWithValue(Map<Key, Value> map, Value value);`

Where's this supported?

Comment: A query like in SQL, would be in java: `map.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getValue().equals(value)).map(Map.Entry::getKey).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: Well, you might want to mention that such manual filtering comes with considerable cost: O(n) instead of anything better.

Answer (score 4):

> it's one that is supported pretty commonly in database languages like SQL

You should read the fine print. Doing `SELECT key WHERE value = ${val}` when `value` is not indexed is really slow because it involves a sequential scan (linear search). To have efficient lookup in both directions, you need two indexes, i.e. two data structures.

Likewise, with two-ways Map data structure, you also need to maintain two trees/hashtables.

> why do no major languages support this relationship?

Because such data structure can be created fairly simply from two regular `Map`s, it's unnecessary to include support for reverse lookup in the regular Map implementation. Also, there's many variations of such data structure, do you want to allow non-unique values? Non-unique keys? How does the structure behave with those? Do you need to preserve ordering on keys? On values? There are endless variations of these Maps, it's impossible for a language to provide them all, and it's fairly straightforward to build them from existing primitives.

Comment: "You should read the fine print": I did, but decided to skip the nuance. You *can* argue it's two data structures, but I'd argue multi-indexed data structures are just one data-structure, because it's still only one set of data.
"Because such data structure can be created fairly simply from two regular Maps": Sure, but if we constrain data structures by "can be implemented via another structure", there's a lot of "vectors with theatrics" out there.

Comment: @deworde You can argue "one" vs "two" data structures all you want, but that doesn't make it so. If there are two ways to traverse or query a container, then there are two kinds of data structures married to each other.

Comment: @bobdalgleish Granted at the theory level, but programming language data structures don't enforce that

Comment: You have already argued that bi-map is not suitable to your needs. What other kinds of bi-directional mapping did you want to support? How is that mapping more natural than any other mapping?

Comment: I'd argue that a SQL `SELECT` isn't a datastructure *at all*. The `TABLE` + `INDEX`es are the datastructure